# Eclipse plugin for better JSP support

Tags: eclipse, jsp, eclipse-plugin

I'm looking for an eclipse plugin which can at least search where the current JSP is included (or the path mentioned for example in custom "include like" tags or comment or anything). Similar like doing copy qualified name and do a file search with the correct path.
*In IDEA it's called Analyze Backward Dependencies and it works for JSPs too (at least for the standard includes).*

A better one would be to show all the JSPs where the current one is included and show all the included JSPs recursively as a tree maybe so I can navigate in it easily. I'm not sure if this can be done to be usable (I think it would be slow).

Another feature I would like if I click on a variable's name it jumps to where it's declared with  even if it's declared in a different JSP.
*IDEA can do this too.*

I have a simple solution for the first one but I can't add more functionality to it as I'm not familiar with the eclipse plugin system and RCP and I don't really have time to learn it.
*And please don't tell me to use IDEA because unfortunately that's not an option at work.*

Comment: None that Ive come across in the past two years.